# "Checkbox"/option type MongoDB schema design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

I am looking to implement some type of checkbox functionality for settings on an account, e.g.

```
option:
    value1: true
    value2: false
    value 3: false
```

My first thought was to have an array key named `option` and then have an array of `Strings` from an `enum`, like so:

```
key: { type: [String], required: true, enum: [
    'value1', 'value2'
 ]}
```

and then I can check to see what options the users has in the array vs. the possible `enum` values...

But maybe I should do something like this;

```
key: {
    value1: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true },
    value2: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true }
}
```

I want this to be super customizable and flexible going forward, so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is better. Much more easy to perform queries.

Comment: Thanks - would that approach scale well, though?

Comment: Yes. In mongo there is no schema which means if you pass more properties it will be saved without changing anything

Comment: Great - thanks! So I can add any more values and it won't affect old entries that don't have the value on it?

Comment: of course you can. Just make sure that if you use a schema in node like mongoose, you set to it to non strict mode so it won't throw away what's not in the schema.